# Filtering JSON API results minimally

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filtering, solana

Im attemtpting to filter results from an API query and was wondering what the best case scenario would be to accomplish this goal.

https://public-api.solscan.io/account/METAmTMXwdb8gYzyCPfXXFmZZw4rUsXX58PNsDg7zjL

Results in:

```
{"lamports":291171461600,"ownerProgram":"TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA","type":"token_account","rentEpoch":283,"account":"METAmTMXwdb8gYzyCPfXXFmZZw4rUsXX58PNsDg7zjL","tokenInfo":{"name":"Solice","symbol":"SLC","price":1.28,"volume":1253400,"decimals":6,"tokenAuthority":null,"supply":"400000000000000","type":"token_address"}}
```

However the intended goal is to only have the value of **"supply"** show, which in this case would be **400000000000000**.

Would need to be as minimal of a solution as possible while being able to be machine read.

My first thought was filter it with JS but that is reliant on processing the JS.

Comment: Either you need to address how the API is sending the data, and reduce it to only the data you need, OR you need to process the data you _do_ get returned to only get the properties you need.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from parsing the JSON into an object, and then extracting the field, you can use a regex and speed it up a bit.

```
const rx = /"supply":"([^"]*)"/
const m = rx.exec(unparsedJson)
const result = m ? m[1] : undefined
```

https://regex101.com/r/Vx3Cp6/1